# converting full-width numerals using xquery

Tags: xml, unicode, xquery

My `$input` XML contains full-width arabic numerals as part of larger segments of cjk text. Whenever I try to do number-related things to this I get `NaN` errors.

Is there a convenient way to convert these numerals to numbers?

```
xquery version "3.0";
1 + １
```

I've tried `number(１)` and `normalize-unicode(１, '')` but no luck.

Comment: It seems Java has https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29 so perhaps you can call into Java from XQuery.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen I couldn't make the Java call work, but I'm going with this for now. ````translate($n/string(), codepoints-to-string((65296, 65297, 65298, 65299, 65300, 65301, 65302, 65303, 65304, 65305)), "0123456789")````

Comment: Looks good, I guess you can shorten `codepoints-to-string((65296, 65297, 65298, 65299, 65300, 65301, 65302, 65303, 65304, 65305))` to `codepoints-to-string(65296 to 65306)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just a couple of notes about some issues I see in your sample code, which I assume were just copy/paste problems but which are worth mentioning just in case: (1) the function is `normalize-unicode`, not `unicode-normalize`, (2) it takes strings (so you need quote around the parameters, e.g., `'１'`), and (3) the 2nd parameter must match one of the known normalization forms: `NFD, NFC, NFKD, NFKC`.

Here's a solution that works for me: use the NFKC (Compatibility Decomposition) form:

```
normalize-unicode('１', 'NFKC')
```

Returns the expected result:

```
1
```

For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-unicode.

Comment: sorry @joewiz for the typo in the OP, i edited the post. According to Xquery 2nd edition  ````normalise-unicode('xxxx','')```` should have picked the default normalisation. I ran your example via exist2.2 but I still get ````NaN```` when trying to perform the addition. I will play with it more and comment here tomorrow.

Comment: As to XQuery 2nd edition (Walmsley's title from O'Reilly), I'm looking at p. 563, where it says that when a zero-length string is provided as the 2nd argument, "No normalization is performed." As to eXist's coverage of this function, there was a fix to `normalize-unicode` in eXist late last June (see https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/pull/687) which should've been included in the eXist 3.0RC1 release in early July 2015, but which wasn't present in 2.2.. In my testing (referenced in my sample code) I'm using a fairly recent build of eXist's development branch. Can you update to 3.0RC1?

Comment: Yes thats the page I was looking at. The default normalisation is set for the whole collection. Anyhow:````1 + number(normalize-unicode('１', 'NFKC'))```` returns ````NaN```` in exists2.2 but works using Saxon. ````1+ number(translate('１', codepoints-to-string((65297)), "1"))```` returns ````2```` Upgrading to RC is not an option right now for the sake of my own sanity. I'll chime in on the GH ticket.

Comment: Understood about the RC. Re: Walmsley, are you referring to this phrase on p. 563? `If $normalizationForm is not provided, NFC is used as a default.` If so, then Walmsley is referring to a single-parameter version of this function, not an empty string for the 2nd parameter. In other words: `normalize-unicode('１')` would result in NFC normalization, but `normalize-unicode('１', '')` would remain *un*-normalized.